# Change Active class CSS in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and Bootsrtrap in my code. I am using [this](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) library for pagination for tables in it. It says here that I can style it with bootstrap, and I wanted to change color of selected number to orange.

[image]

Class of that field is `active` in CSS, and I tried to override its style in my css, but nothing changed. I used this CSS:

```
.active {
    background-color: #FFC773;
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I guess it is very difficult to help you using the info you've provided. At least create a working demo, so we can see your full code in action.

Comment: It is clear since it is referenced that pagination is using twitter bootstrap pagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above given answers are absolutely correct but you should also define the CSS for other states like `focus`, `active` and `hover`:

```
.pagination > .active > a, .pagination > .active > a:focus, .pagination > .active > a:hover, .pagination > .active > span, .pagination > .active > span:focus, .pagination > .active > span:hover {
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: organge;
}
```

This is to avoid various other issues.

Comment: Yeah, this one solved the problem i described below. Those other states were problem. Thanks!

Comment: @FarzadYZ you are right, border color is needed also, otherwise it will look odd. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:visited {
    background-color: #FFC773;
}
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NircMMX4PqD088O8ci1V?p=preview)

Adjust also `border` if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `.active` alone! That is not a proper reference to an active class in a large framework. Just be specific and use this snippet below:

```
.pagination > .active > a {
    background-color: orange;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It is ok when it is first rendered. But when I click other page it changes color to original blue color. Do you know what seems to be problem?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please?